# Facebook Like button links to page with extra querystring values

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Im creating a like button for the web page using

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=252715718165799";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php urlencode(the_permalink()) ?>" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="125" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Which when clicked creates a nice link with an image etc on the users facebook feed, however it links to the page's url with a large querystring appended

```
http://example.com/the/page?fb_action_ids=10200196914349100%2C10200196796266148%2C10200196791466028%2C10200196788705959%2C10200196713104069&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%7B"10200196914349100"%3A10151018009412671%2C"10200196796266148"%3A438799629541199%2C"10200196791466028"%3A336640529795478%2C"10200196788705959"%3A145466598973304%2C"10200196713104069"%3A10150401503152524%2C"10200196704543855"%3A466461563437987%7D
```

This url is arriving at the wordpress powered site and generating 303 forbidden errors.

How do i fix my code / game facebook into linking to pages without the massive querystring?

Comment: Don't know if I got it right, but are tinyurl or other short-urler a way?

Comment: no, that would add a dependency i don't want plus it doesn't work  - tinyurl maintains the full link and redirects to broken url. If only facebook were so reliable